# What could cause a clicking/popping noise when driving straight? (video)

Tags: toyota, noise, drivetrain, axle

Car is automatic front wheel drive Toyota.

The sound comes on light-medium acceleration from speeds 15-35mph even when driving straight and it sounds just like a bad CV joint. In the video I have lifted the wheel and the sounds changed to more like a "grrrr" noise for some reason.

https://vimeo.com/102922065

Comment: You're saying the noise occurs during acceleration, yet in the video, the noise is occurring upon *deceleration*. Just checking to see if this is what you meant, or is there more than one noise going on? Also, were both wheels up in the air when you were doing the video?

Comment: Only one wheel was up. When driving the sound comes while accelerating but its opposite in the video. I should have been clearer. Sorry about that

Comment: Do you have the means to put *both wheels up in the air* and try that again? I am curious whether the differential in the transaxle is making the noise, or if it's something else. When you only have one wheel up in the air, you're giving the diff quite a workout.